# How to "Instantly showing image in UILoader."?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Hello guys I want to switch images when I click at button. So I have this code.

```
var k2:Boolean = false;
btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, imgChanger);
function imgChanger(e:Event):void
{
    if (k2==false)
    {
        img1.myUILoader.source = "img/01.jpg";
        k2 = true;
    }
    else
    {
        img2.myUILoader.source = "img/02.jpg";
    }
}
```

But it isn't good solve for big images, because they are downloaded every time I click button. I want download this image in moment when site is loading.

Any clue?

Comment: why dont you declare an array of loaders and load all your files within the inicialization?

Comment: ok but those two UILoaders are in somes MC. I'm thinking about some container with thouse JPG, but how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

heres what you can use... this loads all images in the background and will give you notification when the first one is loaded so you can display it immediately and when all are loaded... if there are a lot of images i suggest loading only the next one... not all of them to not be a memory hog..

```
var loadedImages:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>;
var imageUrls:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;

// set your image urls, manually, from xml... whatever
imageUrls.push("http://www.mySite.com/image0.jpg");
imageUrls.push("http://www.mySite.com/image1.jpg");
imageUrls.push("http://www.mySite.com/image2.jpg");

// load all image sequentially
var curImageLoadingIndex:int=0;
loadNextImage();
/** loads each image sequentially via recursive calls */
function loadNextImage():void{
    if (curImageLoadingIndex>=imageUrls.length){// done loading
        allImagesLoaded()
    }else{// load next one
        var ldr:Loader=new Loader();
        ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
                    ldr.load(new URLRequest(imageUrls[curImageLoadingIndex]));

        function loaded(event:Event):void{
            ldr.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);//remove listener to prevent memory leaks
            loadedImages.push(ldr);//store loaded image for user whenever needed
            if (curImageLoadingIndex==0)
                firstImageReady();
            curImageLoadingIndex++;//increment to load the next item
            loadNextImage();
        }
    }
}

/** notificaltion when all the images have been loaded */
function allImagesLoaded():void{
    // know all images are loaded here... 
}

/** first image ready to use */
function firstImageReady():void{
    var fistImage:DisplayObject = loadedImages[0];
    // do something with your image here... 
}
```

and if you want to use UILoader just change 2 lines in the request

```
    var ldr:Loader=new UILoader();
    ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,loaded);
```

Comment: I need load them all because I don't know what image I will need.
From what I see, your code do great job if you have some number of img and you display it constantly in same order.

Comment: @Dudi, did this answer your question or do you need more help?

Comment: quick question, where you assign imageUrls[x] to ldr?

Comment: and no that dose not help. Because I can't use it with UILoader/Loader